Problem using websockets in heroku (python)
I'm working on an algorithm that requires financial data as input. The program streams the data via a WebSocket connection to the Tastytrade broker's data distributor and sends it to my algorithm.
However, when deploying this program to Heroku, I get the R10 (Boot Timeout) error. After some research, I learned that this issue is related to Heroku requiring the port to be set via an environment variable. The problem arises when I try to use the port provided by Heroku for the WebSocket client connection.
I am able to connect locally, but when I deploy to Heroku, the connection fails due to using the port Heroku assigns. How can I properly handle the WebSocket connection and port configuration for deployment on Heroku?
Locally it works perfect, for the deployment in Heroku I'm trying something like this, passing the client socket or something, but it doesn't work even locally:
hostname = socket.gethostname()
ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)

client_port = os.getenv('PORT', 12000)
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.bind((ip_address, client_port)) 


ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(dx_url,
                            on_open=on_open,
                            on_message=on_message,
                            on_error=on_error,
                            on_close=on_close
                            )


ws.sock = client_socket

ws.run_forever()

